# ElectronJS React app onclick doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();

const Login = () => {
  function handleClick() {
    const setButton = document.getElementById('submit')
    const username = document.getElementById('floatingInput')
    const password = document.getElementById('floatingPassword')

    setButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const data = {
        user: username.value,
        pass: password.value
      }
      if (username.value != "admin") {
        document.getElementById("floatingInput").setAttribute("className", "input input-bordered input-error")
      } else if (data.pass != "rpsa@219") {
        document.getElementById("floatingPassword").setAttribute("className", "input input-bordered input-error")
      } else {
        history.push('/dash')
        document.getElementById("floatingInput").setAttribute("className", "input input-bordered input-success")
        document.getElementById("floatingPassword").setAttribute("className", "input input-bordered input-success")
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="hero min-h-screen bg-base-200">
      <div className="hero-content flex-col lg:flex-row-reverse">
        <div className="card flex-shrink-0 w-full max-w-sm shadow-2xl bg-base-100">
          <div className="card-body">
            <div className="form-control">
              <label className="label">
                <span className="label-text">Username</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Username" className="input input-bordered" id="floatingInput" defaultValue="admin" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-control">
              <label className="label">
                <span className="label-text">Password</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="password" className="input input-bordered" id="floatingPassword" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-control mt-6">
              <button className="btn btn-outline no-animation btn-warning" id="submit" type="submit" onClick={handleClick}>Login</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

It doesn't work when the submit button is clicked. I wanted it to get the formdata and process it. And redirect the user if it matched my expectation, it's just blank. And there's no error in the dev console neither in the command prompt...

Comment: Directly manipulating the DOM in React is *almost always* the wrong approach.  And adding a click handler inside of a click handler is... strange.  This is probably a good time to start over on this component and implement the functionality you want using React, not copying/pasting vanilla JavaScript code into a React component.